# How can I properly install the latest NVIDIA GeForce drivers on 13.04? (x64)

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'd like to install the latest and greatest straight from NVIDIA, but I get an error message saying I need to log out of an X environment or something. Obviously using the default drivers doesn't deliver the best results.

What exactly can I do to install the latest drivers? If it matters, I have a **2GB GeForce GTX 660 Ti.**

Comment: Can you check on that "X environment", so that we can see what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Before install driver, first close desktop manager:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

For install propretary nvidia driver, follow this step:

1) download driver from: http://www.nvidia.com (select correct gpu, operating system and architecture (32 o 64 bit))

2) *required*: linux headers (if not installed) and other stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

3) ctrl+alt+F4 (or another tty) and login.

4) install driver.

```
sudo sh <script NVIDIA>
```

Installer will configure and build module for your kernel. If anything ok, you must be able to restart your desktop manager with nvidia driver. (nvidia installer write xorg.conf: check correct configuration.)

5) restart desktop manager:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

check if module was mounted on kernel:

```
lsmod | grep nvidia
```

N.B. Possible issue:

gcc version are different between driver and installed copy of gcc

Read /var/log/Xorg.0.log for error, if xserver fail during startup.